# How to change Select field style in sencha

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I want to apply my image to select field in sencha.

So how can I do that.

I have created on class for that

here is code for Select field

```
 xtype: 'selectfield',
                baseCls: 'x-field-select',
                cls: 'selectclass',
                id: 'fieldGeslacht',
                name: 'pickergeslacht',
                options: [
                    {
                        text: 'Man',
                        value: 'Man'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Vrouw',
                        value: 'Vrouw'
                    }
                ],
                usePicker: 'test',
                component: {
                    useMask: true
                }
```

and class of sencha theme that I have changed is here:

```
.selectclass
{    
     overflow: hidden !important;
    width: 90% !important;
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;   
    color: white !important;
    background: url("../img/registreren/2.JPG") no-repeat scroll 100% 0px #FFFFFF; 

}

.x-selectmark-base, .x-field-select, .x-component-outer::after
{
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: 90% !important;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto !important;   
    color: white !important;
    background: url("../img/registreren/2.JPG") no-repeat scroll 100% 0px #FFFFFF !important; 
    -webkit-mask-image:url("../img/registreren/2.JPG") !important;
    -webkit-mask-size: 100% !important;
}
```

But this is not working so please any one help for the applying my style to sencha select field.

Thank you.

Comment: copy + paste your ExtJS code snippet about textfield.

Comment: No this is for Select field.

Comment: Here I have edit my post and add content for Select field

Answer (score 0):

Recently I used the following css to my select field . Hope this helps you

```
.selectfield {
display: block;

.x-label-align-left {
    &:first-child {
      .x-form-label {
        @if $include-border-radius { @include border-top-right-radius($form-fieldset-radius); }
      }
    }

    &:last-child {
      .x-form-label {
        @if $include-border-radius { @include border-bottom-left-radius(0); }
      }
    }        
}
.x-form-label {
    span {
      font-size: 14px;
    }
}    
.x-component-outer {
    &:after {
        margin-top: .5em;
    }
    &:before {
        background: none;
    }
    .x-field-input{
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}
}
```

selectfield sencha

```
           { 
            xtype : 'selectfield',
            cls   : 'selectfield',
            margin  : '5px',
            usePicker : true,
          },
```

Answer (score 0):

Try only the `baseCls` not both so the code will be like this

```
xtype: 'selectfield',
                baseCls: 'selectclass',
                id: 'fieldGeslacht',
                name: 'pickergeslacht',
                options: [
                    {
                        text: 'Man',
                        value: 'Man'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'Vrouw',
                        value: 'Vrouw'
                    }
                ],
                usePicker: 'test',
                component: {
                    useMask: true
                }
```

Comment: In general you don't want to use baseCls.  Use cls when in doubt.

Comment: @Phil but you don't need the style of sencha .. baseCls override the default class name.

Comment: Yes if you want to completely change the UI then use baseCls is the way to go. #emptyCanvas